# Convert String type array to Float type array in swift Cannot assign value of type 'String' to subscript of type 'Double'

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I convert the "numbersString" array that has String type values to a "numbersFloat" array with float type values

The problem is that I keep getting "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to subscript of type 'Double'" as an error

I understand that I am not able to input a Float value to a String subscript, but I can't neither change the Strings because they are comma separated and can't put the values in the array

```
var numbersString = [["564,00", "577,00", "13,00"], ["563,00", "577,00", "14,00"]] → I have
var numbersFloat = [[564.00, 577.00, 13.00], [563.00, 577.00, 14.00]] → I need
```

Things I have tried:

```
for row in 0...numbersString.count-1 {
    for col in 0...numbersString[0].count-1 {
        numbersFloat[row][col] = numbersString[row][col]
    }
}
Error: Cannot assign value of type 'String' to subscript of type 'Double'
```

```
for row in 0...numbersString.count-1 {
    for col in 0...numbersString[0].count-1 {
            var a = table[row][col]
            table[row][col] = Float(a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NumberFormatter` to handle strings containing floats that use commas as their decimal separators. I generally wrap custom formatters in a class. That would look something like this:

```swift
class FloatFormatter {
    let formatter: NumberFormatter
    init() {
        formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
    }

    func float(from string: String) -> Float? {
        formatter.number(from: string)?.floatValue
    }
}
```

Substituting this into your example code (with a fix to the type of your float array) you get:

```swift
var numbersString = [["564,00", "577,00", "13,00"], ["563,00", "577,00", "14,00"]]
var numbersFloat: [[Float]] = [[564.00, 577.00, 13.00], [563.00, 577.00, 14.00]]

let floatFormatter = FloatFormatter()
for row in 0...numbersString.count-1 {
    for col in 0...numbersString[0].count-1 {
        numbersFloat[row][col] = floatFormatter.float(from: numbersString[row][col])!
    }
}
```

This works, but it's not very Swifty. Using map would be better (that way you do not need to worry about matching the sizes of your arrays and pre-allocating the float array).

```swift
let floatFormatter = FloatFormatter()
let numbersString = [["564,00", "577,00", "13,00"], ["563,00", "577,00", "14,00"]]
let numbersFloat = numbersString.map { (row: [String]) -> [Float] in
    return row.map { stringValue  in
        guard let floatValue = floatFormatter.float(from: stringValue) else {
            fatalError("Failed to convert \(stringValue) to float.")
        }
        return floatValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but when casting to Float it would fail if there is fraction digits in the string. "1,00" would work but "1,10" wouldn't. I will investigate it a bit further

Comment: @LeoDabus Both of those are surprising!  Certainly just using `Double(_ value: String)?` would simplify things. Strange that `Float(_ value: String)?` is not consistent.

Comment: but the issue is that I am trying to find a way to make it generic and I don’t find any string initializer on the FloatingPoint protocol while for the integers there is on for FixedWidthInteger protocol

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2924552-init

Comment: It works for CGFloat and Float64 as well but not for Float, Float80 and Decimal. Looks like it only works for 64bit

Comment: It is probably related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776595/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
var numbersString = [["564.00", "577.00", "13.00"], ["563.00", "577.00", "14.00"]]

var numbersFloat: [[Float]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numbersString[0].count), count: numbersString.count)

print(numbersFloat.count)
for row in 0...numbersString.count - 1 {
    for col in 0...numbersString[0].count - 1 {

        print(row, col, numbersString[row][col])
        print(Float(numbersString[row][col]) ?? 0)
        numbersFloat[row][col] =  Float(numbersString[row][col]) ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I think one of the things the OP was struggling with was that their strings used commas as the decimal separator. If you run your snippet with their original data it will fail.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I like your answer much better.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with both "." and "," separator.

```
var numbersString = [["564,00", "577,00", "13,00"], ["563,00", "577,00", "14,00"]]

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
let decimalSeparator = ","
numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = decimalSeparator

let numbersFloat = numbersString.map({ $0.compactMap({ numberFormatter.number(from: $0.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: decimalSeparator))?.floatValue })})
```

For everyone: NumberFormatter has `.locale` property and when formatter is created, locale is set to current device locale. But decimal separators differs in different countries. It can lead to very unpleasant bugs when everything works good for you and even for QAs, but doesn't work for users in production. So it is always best option to control String-to-Double conversion in described way.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why do you think an array would have values with different decimal separators? BTW This would fail if there is groupingSeparator (most likely to be a period when the decimalSeparator is a comma) `"1.564,00"`. The correct approach is to use the proper Locale.

Comment: It is not matter of input data, it is matter of your formatter) For example, you have string "1,00". And you have two users, first from USA (decimal separator ".") and second from Russia (decimal separator ","). Then if you try to get number from input string using NumberFormatter, then user from Russia will success, but user from USA will fail.                  You are right about grouping separator, it won't work if it has one.

Comment: We are not talking about a text field

Comment: Got it, you are right. In this case with static data your answer is more suitable.