# How can I have custom type as return function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a customMultiple function which take 2 value and multiple them, the Type of first value is known and it is an Int, but the type of value2 is unknown, it could be Int or CGFloat or . . ., Xcode take error, How can I run this function?

```
func customMultiple<T: Numeric>(value1: Int, value2: T) -> T {
    return T(value1) * value2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one fallible initializer [init(exactly:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric/2886795-init) available for numeric types:

```
init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger
```

You need to coerce your Int or any BinaryInteger to the resulting type (Float, Double, Int or any numeric type that conforms to Numeric protocol) and multiply it:

```
func customMultiple<T: Numeric, U: BinaryInteger>(value1: U, value2: T) -> T? {
    guard let value1 = T(exactly: value1) else { return nil }
    return value1 * value2
}
```

---

```
let test = customMultiple(value1: 256, value2: CGFloat(4))        // 1024
let test1 = customMultiple(value1: 256, value2: UInt8(4))         // nil
let test2 = customMultiple(value1: Int.max, value2: CGFloat(1))   // nil
```

Comment: thanks, if we exactly know about value1 that always have a value, could we done it without facing fallible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776595/2303865

Comment: There is no guarantee that the resulting value can represent exactly the value that’s being coerced